# Laravel Api routes fail to load. 404 not found

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel

For reference I have been working with this tutorial https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-time-tracker-with-laravel-5-and-angularjs-part-2.

I wanted to become more familiar with laravel 5 since I had previously only used 4 and found the above tutorial which also mixed in a little angular js. I followed part one and two of the tutorials to the letter and set up a database using mysql and phpmyadmin like directed.

I get to a section about halfway through which sets up a group route with the prefix api to pull seeded data from the database and display it in the view.

```
// app/Http/routes.php

 ...

// A route group allows us to have a prefix, in this case api
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api'), function()
{
    Route::resource('time', 'TimeEntriesController');
    Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
});
```

After this point I go to the page and the area that was previously rendered with data from a file instead of a database is now blank. If I inspect the element I get "failed to load resource the server responded with a status of 404 (not found)" and it displays my path time-tracker-2/public/api/time.

The routes work with these two controllers to populate the page with userdata from my database

```
// app/Http/Controllers/TimeEntriesController.php

...

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;    
use App\TimeEntry;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

class TimeEntriesController extends Controller {

    // Gets time entries and eager loads their associated users
    public function index()
    {
        $time = TimeEntry::with('user')->get();

        return $time;
    }


// app/Http/Controllers/UsersController.php

...

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UsersController extends Controller {

    // Gets all users in the users table and returns them
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all();

        return $users;
    }
```

Again I haven't worked much with Laravel and this is my first time messing with angular so I don't know if I am missing something super obvious or what the deal is. I have checked over all my code and compared it to the sample code and they are identical other than my database information. I have also scrapped the project and started from scratch and still get the same error when I get to this point.

Any sort of direction to look would be greatly appreciated because this error is driving me nuts.

Comment: Are you sure this is what its supposed to be? `time-tracker-2/public/api/time.` Why the `public` folder? I would think it should be `time-tracker-2/api/time`

Comment: also, `php artisan route:list` will show you all your routes to confirm what the URLs should be.

Comment: I forgot the route list as another reason I was thrown off. When I do route list I can see all the routes listed exactly as they should be but I still get 404.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember to point on the public folder, not on the root folder. That's why your URL is `time-tracker-2/public/api/time` and not `time-tracker-2/api/time`. This should fix your 404 error.

Comment: I've haven't been able to tweak my URLs to cut out public since switching to my mac. Ill take another crack at that and see if I can get rid of that 404 and check back.